# Doctrine don't fine findBy PhpUnit

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit

I'm novice about phpunit.

I use this snippet to mock my EntityManager

```
$emMock = $this->getMock('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager',
            array('getRepository', 'getClassMetadata', 'persist', 'flush'), array(), '', false);
    $emMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->will($this->returnValue(new \it\foo\Entity\File()));
    $emMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('persist')
            ->will($this->returnValue(null));
    $emMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getClassMetadata')
            ->will($this->returnValue((object) array('name' => 'aClass')));
    $emMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('flush')
            ->will($this->returnValue(null));
```

When I run my test I have this error

> Error: Call to undefined method it\foo\Entity\File::findBy()

How can I mock this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code, you will see, that at least one line of it calls `getRepository()` and uses the result to apply function `findBy()` on it. This is a very standard behavior of a Doctrine2 program.

You are mocking only the `EntityManager` - you have the mock in the variable `$emMock`. One of the (mocked) functions, `getRepository()` returns an object of class `\it\foo\Entity\File`, which you create in line 5.

I suppose that class `\it\foo\Entity\File` doesn't implement the same interface as a Doctrine2 repository, at least it obviously doesn't implement `findBy()`, so the error message occurs.

To solve this problem, you need to replace the return value of the mock function for `getRepository` with either e real Repository (which is normally not what you want in a unit test) or another mock:

```
$repoMock = $this->getMock('Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository', [], [], '', false);
$emMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getRepository')
        ->will($this->returnValue($repoMock);
```

Most likely you have to mock some of the functions in the Repository as well, for example `findBy()` which may return the list of entries you want your test to work with.

Comment: Did this answer help or what is missing?